# Swift - Accessing Dictionary Content & Copy to Array

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I am using Firebase for the backend, and am returning data in the following format (as printed in console):

```
{
    dueDate = "12-12-2016";
    orderNotes = None;
    orderNumber = XBQDIaMo;
    retailerName = HomeBase;
    shippingAddressType = Home;
    status = Pending;
    username = ksja;
}
{
    dueDate = "10-08-2016";
    orderNotes = None;
    orderNumber = ZDkumaBj0ohS;
    retailerName = BestBuy;
    shippingAddressType = Home;
    status = Pending;
    username = ksja;
}
```

I have an array of custom class type. In the array, each element will be an order object and contain one of the two items above (could be more in the future of course). I am wondering how can I get the items in the above structure into the array?

```
ordersArray[0].status = //I want the value here from the above above
ordersArray[1].status = //I want the value of the second object above in array
```

So far the code leading me to print out the above structure is:

```
let reference = Firebase(url:"https://something.firebaseio.com/orders/")
        reference.childByAppendingPath("\(reference.authData.uid)/")
        reference.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                //print(snapshot.value)
                for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                    //print(item.value)
                    for orderItem in item.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                       print(orderItem.value)
                       //print(orderItem.value.valueForKey("orderNumber"))

                    }

                }
            }else{
                print("No Snapshot?!")
            }
        })
```

I really appreciate the help with this one...thanks

Update: As requested, This is the structure I have as provided by firebase data browser:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your data structure? You shouldn't need to have a doubly nested a loop. If I could see a your data structure I could help get your the array you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidEast hi david...thanks for the response. Post updatd with structure as can be seen in the firebase data browser.